# How do I specify the order of multiple SpringApplication sources to load?

Tags: java, spring-boot

How do I specify the order of multiple SpringApplication sources to load?

new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Config1.class, xmlFileResource, Config2.class);

I want to load sources in the parameter order,but when it packaged and run in tomcat , the result is not right.

Comment: Did you read about `@Order(int value)` in spring ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna How `@Order` apply in xmlFileResource?

Comment: It can be applied for class only. May I know why you want to load xml resources in some kind of order ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I packaged some bean for developers.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna the  content of xml can dynamic created, which is not supported by java class